# Update statement does not run in a stored procedure but alone work fine

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have these update statements as mention below for updating null or blank columns in a table:

```
UPDATE ASPECT.DEALER_MASTER 
 SET RO_DLR_GRP='IND' 
 WHERE RO_DLR_GRP IS NULL OR TRIM(RO_DLR_GRP)='';
```

and

```
UPDATE ASPECT.DEALER_MASTER 
 SET DEALER_GRP=TRIM(RO_DLR_GRP) 
 WHERE DEALER_GRP IS NULL OR TRIM(DEALER_GRP)='';
```

These statements work fine when I run them alone, but when I used these statements in astored procedure they never updated the table.

Why is it so?

Comment: How about sharing that stored procedure, so that we know what you were doing? Are there errors or just no rows updated? Are there rows that would qualify? Is there anything in db2diag.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem was inside the procedure body with statement was not properly terminated.Update statement was correct.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is select data first like

SELECT  * FROM ASPECT.DEALER_MASTER  WHERE RO_DLR_GRP IS NULL OR TRIM(RO_DLR_GRP)='';

To make sure result is return.
If no data return, there is nothing to update.